# Definition of limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

If $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $0 \leq a < \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon >0$, then

$$ a = 0 \tag{A}$$

However, the defnition of a limit of a sequence is: the limit of a sequence of real numbers $x_n$ is $x \in \mathbb{R}$, if there exists some $N$ s.t. for $n \geq N$ we have

$$|x_n - x|< \epsilon$$

for any $\epsilon > 0$.

So, from $(A)$, doesn't that mean for $n \geq N$ we have $x_n = x$, which is false?

Comment: The limit of the sequence is $x$ if for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $|x_n-x|< \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N.$ You have the correct statements, but not in the correct order. The value $\epsilon$ is chosen first, and $N$ depends on $\epsilon$ generally.

Comment: @ChrisLeary: Your comment should be an answer. I'm extremely irked when textbooks write the way quoted in the question, because it is not clear whether "for any $ε > 0$" comes before or after "there exists some [natural] $N$".

Comment: @user21820 - I agree. The writing in textbooks can be surprisingly sloppy at times.

Answer (score 3):

The $N$ in "exists some $N$" depends on your choice of $\epsilon$, and will intuitively be larger for smaller $\epsilon$. So for a fixed $n$, the inequality $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$ does not hold for all $\epsilon$ simultaneously.

In contrast, in your first line $a < \epsilon$ holds for all $\epsilon$ simultaneously, so the conclusion (A) does hold.

Answer (score 2):

The limit of the sequence is $x$ if for each $\epsilon >0$ there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $|x_n−x|<\epsilon$ for all $n≥N.$ You have the correct statements, but not in the correct order. The value $\epsilon$ is chosen first, and $N$ depends on $\epsilon$ generally.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement in your question means the following :

> **The** only non-negative real number less than every positive real number is $0$.

This is talking about a specific real number (note the bold **the**). It is rather amazing and highly unfortunate that modern textbooks have been able to convert this fact from 7th grade math into a seemingly high brow stuff.

The definition of limit does not deal with a specific number. The expression $|x_{n} - x|$ involves the variable $n$ which itself depends on $\epsilon$. So the situation is different from what is being mentioned in statement $(A) $.